# Collect logs from docker container path to Filebeat docker container

Tags: filebeat

I'm currently running a Docker container with Filebeat version 8.9.1. I'd like to access logs from other containers within the Docker Filebeat container using paths, without relying on the volumes approach to access shared files. Is there any way to achieve this?

I've noticed that the `type: docker` method has been deprecated. I'm wondering if there's an alternative approach to achieve similar functionality.
Like this way:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: container
  containers.ids: "{container_id}"
  paths:
  // docker container path
  - /var/log/nginx/access.log
```